# Refresh the parent window from the child window in javascript

Tags: javascript, window.location, window.opener

I have looked for awhile and cannot find an answer that fits my needs. I have a page that pops a window (window.open), logs the user in (creates a cookie, set session) then redirects to another page. While the modal is redirecting, I would like to refresh the parent page, so all the good stuff that I just did will be recognized by the parent. I have tried window.opener and stuff like that. Can someone help me out a little? Thanks

Comment: Did you mean "Refresh the parent from the CHILD javascript"? I like green chili, being from New Mexico, but I don't know what a chili is in this context.

Comment: window.parent isn't it? `window.parent.frames[0]` or similar https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM

Comment: window.opener is usually what you will call on the child window. Can you show your script your using to open this new window?

Answer (score 10):

[`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) in the popup will refer to the `window` object of the opening window, so of course you should be able to call `window.opener.location.reload();`. Provided you don't run afoul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), the popup window can call scripts and manipulate properties on the parent window object just like code in the parent can.

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/itono3/3) demonstrating the child calling back to a function on the parent, and also manipulating the parent directly. The full code for this is quoted below.

But that example didn't do *exactly* what you said, so I've [done this one as well](http://jsbin.com/itono3/5), which has the child refreshing the parent page via `window.opener.location.reload()`.

Parent code of first live example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Parent Window</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='button' id='btnOpen' value='Open Window'>
  <div id='display'></div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  (function() {
    var btnOpen = document.getElementById('btnOpen');
    btnOpen.onclick = btnOpenClick;

    function btnOpenClick() {
      window.open('http://jsbin.com/ehupo4/2');
    }

    // Make the callback function available on our
    // `window` object. I'm doing this explicitly
    // here because I prefer to export any globals
    // I'm going to create explicitly, but if you
    // just declare a function in a script block
    // and *not* inside another function, that will
    // automatically become a property of `window`
    window.callback = childCallback;
    function childCallback() {
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
          'Got callback from child window at ' + new Date();
    }
  })();
</script>
</html>​
```

(You don't **have** to use a scoping function as I did above, but it's useful to keep your globals contained.)

Child code of first live example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Child Window</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>I'm the child window</p>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  if (window.opener) {
    // Call the provided callback
    window.opener.callback();

    // Do something directly
    var p = window.opener.document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = "I was added by the child directly.";
    window.opener.document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
</script>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 1):

window.parent.top.location = window.parent.top.location; (or something similiar to that will do it)

Comment: window.opener is perhaps better

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other suggestions work (Remember to test in all major browsers), you can also try passing a reference of the parent window to the child window explicitly.  Because `window.open()` should return a reference to the child window.. so you can do  `child = window.open()`  and then you can do something like `child.myParent = window`

Comment: Very true. `window.opener` is reliable barring the SOP, and this will run afoul of the SOP as well, but good to have options. You have to deal with timing a bit, which is part of why I prefer to have the child call the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with submitting a form in a modal via ajax and need the page underneath (parent page) to reload. `window.location.reload();` worked for me.