# PHP poup can return value to the form from when it opens?

Tags: php

I have so many records to print. I need "EDIT" and "DELETE"  for that in one page so, I just made listing (that name list.php)  with EDIT DELETE Link.

I used JS to open NewWindow(listedit.php) when Click on Edit. Records have been updated from that poupup window. When records has been updated I want to reload my list.php when record have been updated from listedit.php I want to reload the list.php.

can any one suggest where and with what I can do it?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762329/refresh-the-parent-window-from-the-child-window-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

in your popup page:

```
$('#closeButton').click(function(e) {
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

this lines reloads the parent page and closes the popup.